# Seemingly incorrect elasticsearch folder

Tags: php, powershell, elasticsearch, compiler-errors, download

I downloaded elasticsearch from https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.6.0.zip.

It seems the folder is incorrect or I'm doing something wrong.

I opened the folder but:

1. I could not see any X86 executable though I'm on a 32bit PC and the
   name of the folder(directory) is
   `elasticsearch-7.0.0-beta1-windows-x86_64`.When I open the extracted
   folder,this is what I see:

   [Snapshot of downloaded elasticsearch `bin`folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl5A1.png)
2. Also,When I run `bin\elasticsearch.bat`,i get an empty console.Absolutely nothing shows.The console is blank.
3. According to https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch,I'm supposed to  `Run curl http://localhost:9200/ or Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:9200 with PowerShell`,Neither of them work,When I try the both of them,I get this:
    [Errors  displayed in Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0777.png)

These are the errors:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\o.o amoo> curl http://localhost:9200/^Vcurl http://localhost:9200/curl http://localhost:9200/curl http://loc
alhost:9200/curl http://localhost:9200/^V
The term 'curl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelli
ng of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:5
+ curl <<<<  http://localhost:9200/▬curl http://localhost:9200/curl http://localhost:9200/curl http://localhost:9200/cu
rl http://localhost:9200/▬
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (curl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\o.o amoo> curl
The term 'curl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelli
ng of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:5
+ curl <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (curl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\o.o amoo> Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:9200
The term 'Invoke-RestMethod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Che
ck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ Invoke-RestMethod <<<<  http://localhost:9200
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-RestMethod:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\o.o amoo>
PS C:\Users\o.o amoo>
PS C:\Users\o.o amoo>
PS C:\Users\o.o amoo>
```

Please help,I'm getting so frustrated.

Comment: You're probably gonna have better chances in the official discuss https://discuss.elastic.co/

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Have you ever used elasticsearch?

Comment: Go in elastic logs folder to see error. I thinck you didnot have java jre on your computer. elastic needs java to work.

Comment: I have java  jre on my computer.

Comment: @LeBigCat any other ideas?

Comment: @LeBigCat How do I check if I have java jre?

Comment: [an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)  ... that's valid for error messages as well.  ;-)

Comment: we cant ever know what s happen on your screeshot :). To start let s be sure elastic didnotstart, go in brower, and tell us if http://localhost:9200/ respond (of course start elasticsearch.bat first)

Comment: @Olaf Wait I have to manually write down the entire error?

Comment: @LeBigCat No `localhost:9200` is not connecting

Comment: ok go in windows, system properties tell us if JAVA_HOME is set and what is its value

Comment: @LeBigCat Soory but what don't you understand in the screenshot

Comment: @LeBigCat Ok i'm doing that..please wait

Comment: @LeBigCat Yup.It's set,this is the variable:`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`

Comment: @PrimeJay  Copy the error and post it here formatted as code. You may want to re-read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @Olaf Do you mean the PowerSell error?

Comment: @Olaf Done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: ( Most important )

> Make sure you check whether Java is installed in your system or not
>   (cmd > java -version) & Set JAVA_HOME to the Jdk path in Environment
>   variables.

Step 2:

> Open command prompt with run as administrator :
>
> cmd > cd paste_folder_path/bin/elasticsearch.bat
>   // This will start
>   the elasticsearch server.

Step 3:

> localhost:9200

If that doesn't work try with elasticsearch version 6.6.0...You are trying with the beta version which might still be buggy hence causing some issues.

Comment: cmd is command prompt (in your case powershell i guess). java -version will tell you whether java is properly installed in your system or not.

Comment: Sorry could you give me an example of `_folder_path/bin/elasticsearch` because I have different elasticsearch dolders

Comment: Is this ok?:`C:\Users\o.o amoo\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.0.0-beta1-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.0.0-beta1\bin`

Comment: The path of the elasticsearch folder where you extracted the zip files. eg : Your powershell command should be something similar to this, eg: cd C:\Users\PrimeJay\Desktop\Elasticsearch\elasticsearch-6.6.0\bin\elasticsearch

Comment: Yes! This should be your command : cd C:\Users\o.o amoo\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.0.0-beta1-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.0.0-beta1\bin\elasticsearch

Comment: The directory name is invalid

Comment: The file exists but I don;t know why it says `the directory name is invalid`...ooh I'm sooo close

Comment: You might be copying the wrong path. Try running the elasticsearch file from bin folder directly with powershell instead.

Comment: I dont get...elaborate

Comment: Whaen I pasted the Directory name in windows Explorer,it worked fine..it attempted to open elastic search

Comment: Run the elasticsearch file from the bin folder. If that doesn't work try with elasticsearch version 6.6.0...You are trying with the beta version which might be still buggy hence causing some issues.

Comment: Is it elasticsearch or elasticsearch.bat ?

Comment: run elasticsearch.bat

Comment: EDIT YOUR ANSWER